# How to Apply search in ng-pdfviewer in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using "https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer" to view pdf in popup. But it will display one page at a time. I want to apply search on popup so that i can move to a specific page by search in pdf. Please share your comments if anyone have use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a search with the page number,

```
angular.module('testApp', ['pdf'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'pdfDelegate',
  function($scope, pdfDelegate, $log) {
    $scope.pdfUrl = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/149125/relativity.pdf';
}]);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/NdxMjz)**

Comment: want to search by a string in pdf. because it is showing one page at a time. if i have 18 pages. i want to search by a keyword, like if it is a job related document. then i want to search by some keyword whether it is in document or not.

Comment: You might have to write your own directive for that :) it does not come with the library